# How do I use the GRAKN.AI REST API?

Tags: rest, vaticle-typedb

I am trying to make GRAKN API calls from a Chrome extension, but I cannot figure out how to make those calls.

I have only ever used heavily documented APIs (Twitter, Facebook, etc.) so I am not sure how to go about reading and writing from an to the database from Javascript just based off of [reading this](http://links.b.mail-zr.com/wf/click?upn=7PAOVXjQKo5QhGHLURDL7G7DCUxvT0Wikl38nwrWBsM61lawxxZ-2B9RpWwJAOY1WK_bhKCJs1lEivQwrg0picuDknch-2BP7Rp5RO-2Bl6ZOSvKeQIGY7XP6724nHRyL5KQhrkXll3oeNO8UNIu7B7NVt-2FdNPjb8Qm0Ojphuu-2FfJyM28ygRmm0k1-2BwvUwmgY69YxIfUqKxa-2FOcoTdSTgg3XtcABFnu-2BfXvitMUc0bguaa-2FQD0sG4BO4FjkfJ0DDXgUUBUnIB-2FFDi7a8VC5sIZWi1Y9eaj2RnMViHD5zI920BK-2FztWzBEvv2t4RmX40CxEc7MkzlO-2Bi-2FcuLdDbvq1UWqijsD49gqwRsM45fgsetFplcoyLza8s0NAdQ6hwh7636HanoqQl47LGvNpRONSKzQsChl7SZzucikLOlRoGhpMZ5TnZNRVQ-2BMxiXfBrUj4AdKJKgIQiFuUXX-2Ffs1RisoWQapPtxW8EF2HElehh0CNxaLFtfftwyL9DpFQUdyTvP2SZA5oOsHvKRQpUYA1AWXXcbYvxctmcBuIwZ31uFnHhPgkI-2BhXeLpbqWHXtqLxJGJHZ6PL23dvrzPlvN8kHr55Ch55CJloh2ptHLsxhR6ZOv9LHiVb89Oyu51LU0efr4jfSwkMAHNSUOUOGEOVu0YivUGeLqD49JsmKSuBMfzjlZDSQHIjJtMomAn5K8KA1XG7Ous).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, we have a Node.js driver you can use to communicate to Grakn (it works with gRPC over HTTP2), so that you don't have to worry about learning REST endpoints: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grakn. What are you trying to build?

Comment: @zizzo As far as I know, I can't use node.js in a chrome extension. I am trying to build a clone of the Instapaper/Pocket web clipper that will save webpage content to grakn.

Comment: you can use version 0.1.1 of that driver, it is compatible with javascript given that still uses REST apis: in the readme there is a quickstart https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn-node/tree/0.1.1 - also join our stack channel if you need more help, it's easier to help from there

Answer (score 0):

The Grakn REST API is specified here:

https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/blob/master/docs/api.yaml

Each path under 'paths' can be adjoined to the base url (localhost:4567, by default), e.g.,

localhost:4567/kb

There are further paths in the results you can then follow.